# How to hide the mouse cursor?

Tags: objective-c, macos

How do you make the mouse cursor disappear in Objective-C? (just the visible mouse cursor, the mouse still needs to work)

Comment: I figured it out: `[NSCursor hide]`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
[NSCursor hide];
```

then to show the cursor again:

```
[NSCursor unhide];
```

Answer (score 8):

In Swift

```
NSCursor.hide()
NSCursor.unhide()
```